# What to do if I forget how to recite an ayah during prayer?

Tags: salat, quran-recitation, surah, mistake

What should I do when I am reciting a surah after surah *Fatiha* (Suppose surah *Zilzal*) and near the middle I unfortunately forget the right ayaht?

If I can't remember the ayaht within a short time what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible to recite a portion of a surah with a minimum of 3 iyayt after surah fatiha. If one forgets then attempt to remember if you cannot then go to ruku and continue.

Answer (score 0):

It is then better to go for salam and restart your prayers.Or if you realized that you commited some mistake during the prayers so dont restart instead do SAJDAH SAHW.

Answer (score 0):

If you are leading the salat in congregation as an Imam, wait about 15 seconds for someone in the congregation to correct you.  If not just recite another surah that you know for sure and go to ruku.

At the end of the salah before you salut the angels on both sides perform 2 more sajdas for repentance for the mistake.

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Your answer would benefit from some evidences to support your claims (see [answer].